# What is the sequence of scripts execution in Marketing cloud ? ampscript executes first or SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

What is the sequence of scripts execution in Marketing cloud ? ampscript executes first or SSJS ? or it will be top to bottom ?

Comment: Ampscript executes top down

Comment: SSJS allows writing and calling functions, but with this exception it will also be interpreted top down. so generally speaking, AMPScript/ SSJS are both top down, none of the two languages inherently executes first or second. As you can also pass data from AMPScript into SSJS and vice versa, using `Variable.GetValue` and `Variable.SetValue` SSJS methods, chaining of scripts of both languages is possible by just writing them in the right order. It is not per se recommended as it plausibly won't help performance, but it certainly is possible and sometimes pretty useful.